# gruntjs: How to install and get started with grunt?

Tags: gruntjs

I have installed grunt in ubuntu using command:

```
npm install -g grunt
npm install -g grunt-cli
```

but now if i try to do grunt init it is throwing me an error.

`A valid Gruntfile could not be found. Please see the getting started guide for more information on how to configure grunt: http://gruntjs.com/getting-started Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

grunt by its self doesn't have the 'init' command.

In order to use grunt you need a `Gruntfile.js` and `package.json` files

**updated**

you can set up grunt with these simple steps:

**1:**

```
npm init
```

after running the above command, you will be prompted with some questions. for now you can go ahead and hit 'enter' until it is finished.

a new file was created, called package.json.

this file hold information about the project, along with a list of dependencies.

**2:**

grunt has many nice packages, such as **jshint**.
let's install it with this command:

```
npm install grunt-contrib-jshint --save
```

now a 'node_modules' directory was created, with grunt/jshint in it.

the **--save** flag also added jshint to our package.json file.

---

Now we need to setup the **Gruntfile.js**:

create a file named Gruntfile.js, with this content in it:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    jshint: {
      all: ['Gruntfile.js', '1.js']
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint:all']);
};
```

note that we are telling jshint what files to work on, also we are loading the jshint task,

and registering the 'default' task (when typing 'grunt' in the console).

create a file named **1.js**, and run:

```
grunt
```

you will see your new task running (hinting the .js files)

---

See this nice 'beginners-guide-to-grunt' [tutorial](http://mattbailey.io/a-beginners-guide-to-grunt/), to understand the concepts of:

```
node_modules/
package.json
Gruntfile.js
```

Comment: ved@ved-Vostro-3446:~/WebstormProjects/wodrob$ grunt
Running "jshint:gruntfile" (jshint) task
>> 1 file lint free.

Running "jshint:lib_test" (jshint) task
>> 0 files linted. Please check your ignored files.

Running "qunit:files" (qunit) task
Warning: 0/0 assertions ran (0ms) Use --force to continue.

Comment: delete existing package.json, then run 'npm init'

Comment: @Ved follow the instructions. have you deleted the package.json and ran 'npm init' ?

Comment: yes. after running npm init,What to write in Test command: '', and git repository:''?

Comment: this is eroor: Running "jshint:gruntfile" (jshint) task
>> 1 file lint free.

Running "jshint:lib_test" (jshint) task
>> 0 files linted. Please check your ignored files.

Running "qunit:files" (qunit) task
Warning: 0/0 assertions ran (0ms) Use --force to continue.

Comment: @Ved leave those fields blank.. since this is the comments section, we should move on to chat for farther discusion.

Comment: sure, let's try it (first time using the chat): http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66034/between-nbaleli-and-ved

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66036/discussion-between-nitsan-baleli-and-ved).

Comment: I did it.. It will not be possible without your support. Accepting your answer.